# JDK 1.8 on RHEL 6.5 : Can't import JTable

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, rhel6

I'm using Eclipse as IDE on RHEL 6.5 with JDK 1.8

When I try to declare some object of `JTable`, it doesn't find appropriate import package/class.

When I manually try to write import statement, it only shows up to `javax.swing`, but it doesn't show `JTable` there after.

```
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class JTableTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JTable obj1 = new JTable();
    }
}
```

it only happens when using JTable other imports are not affected...

[image]

Comment: Perhaps post your code? The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) says JTable is under javax.swing, so it's definitely something silly.

Comment: is it possible to check if my jdk contains JTable or not?

Comment: import javax.swing.JTable;


public class JTableTest {

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  JTable obj1 = new JTable();
  
 }
}

Comment: In your question, please?

Comment: and just to mention that it doesn't happen with JDK 1.7

Comment: As @hd1 requests, edit your question to include new information, especially code that's hard to read in a comment. See also [*How to Install Oracle Java 8 (JDK 8u5) on CentOS/RHEL 6/5 and Fedora*](http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/).

Comment: i'm having this issue with eclipse 3.7 on win7x64 (pic is from me) - and yes, the same here, it works perfect with java7 and java6 but java8 (jdk1.8.0_20 and jre1.8.0_20) **DON'T** work...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using JDK 1.8.0_20 and Eclipse 4.4.0.  Eclipse kept saying "*The import javax.swing.JTable cannot be resolved*", and "*JTable cannot be resolved to a type*".  This also wasn't happening in JDK 7 and 6  From my estimation, there must be something wrong with Swing with JDK 8.

To solve the issue, I went to find a *.jar* file of the Swing package that would contain a working JTable class.  After downloading one from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavartjarstubs150jar.htm, and incorporating it into my build path, JTable once again worked.

This is not the ideal solution, as the *.jar* file contains a lot of redundant packages already included in JDK 1.8.0_20, but it was the only solution I could come up, besides downgrading to JDK 7 or 6.

I do hope Oracle does fix this issue soon in future releases of JDK 8.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i downloaded the stubs! i added them to into my build path ...and **IT WORKED** thanks a lot (+1)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is some compatibility issue with JDK 1.8.0_20 and Eclipse 4.4.0. As it works fine if we refer to JTable in a simple java program written outside Eclipse on the same environment.

After moving to Eclipse 4.5.1 (Eclipse Mars) the problem is resolved.

Hope this is the right solution.